# connection problem(JTextfield, Jtable, sql database)

Tags: java, sql-server, swing

i'm junho who is stuying JAVA, SQL.

Now i'm struggling with this below problem.

firstly, when i tried to put 20020202 in this field, it occurred error about unexpected datatype. However, i don't know how to change number to 'Date'

Secondly, i don't know how to make JTable method to input into this below part.

```
                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                        Vector row = new Vector(columns);
                        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                            row.addElement(resultSet.getObject(i));
                        }
                        data.addElement(row);
                    }
```

because if i dont put the below code,

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
JTable table1 = new JTable(model);
table1.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
table1.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table1);        
scrollPane.setBounds(10, 53, 600, 200);
addGrid(gbl,gbc,scrollPane,0,4,2,3,0,0);
```

the table doesn't show up.

So, i m wondering how to fix this problem.
my writing skill for english is not good. So, it is not going to be enough info for you.
i wish someone gives advice for me.

this is whole code that i wrote.
i hope it will help you to understand what i am struggling with.
thank you so much.

---

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class DbPanel extends JPanel{



public DbPanel() {

    Vector columnNames = new Vector();
    Vector data = new Vector();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();   //
    JPanel panel2 =new JPanel();


    GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    setLayout(gbl);


    //DB 관리
/*      String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
    String user = "madang";
    String password = "madang";

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        String sql = "select * from STOCK_INFO order by DATE_STOCK";
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
            columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnName(i));
        }
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Vector row = new Vector(columns);
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                row.addElement(resultSet.getObject(i));
            }
            data.addElement(row);
        }
        resultSet.close();
        statement.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }*/
    //DB 끝


     JLabel label = new JLabel("start_date");
        addGrid(gbl,gbc,label,0,0,1,1,0,0);

        JTextField textfield = new JTextField(8);
        addGrid(gbl,gbc,textfield,0,1,1,1,0,0);


        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("end_date");
        addGrid(gbl,gbc,label2, 2,0,1,1,0,0);
        JTextField textfield2 = new JTextField(8);
        addGrid(gbl,gbc,textfield2, 2,1,1,1,0,0);

        JButton btn = new JButton("search");
        addGrid(gbl, gbc, btn, 2, 4, 1, 3, 0, 0);


        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Stock_database");
        lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
       /* lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 11, 927, 31);*/
        addGrid(gbl,gbc,lblNewLabel,0,3,4,1,1,0);

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,                 columnNames);
        JTable table1 = new JTable(model);
        table1.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        table1.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table1);        
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 53, 600, 200);
        addGrid(gbl,gbc,scrollPane,0,4,2,3,0,0);

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
                String user = "madang";
                String password = "madang";

                try {
                    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,     user, password);
                    String sql = "select * from stock_info     between"+textfield.getText()+"and"+textfield2.getText();
                    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                    ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
                    int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                        columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnName(i));
                    }
                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                        Vector row = new Vector(columns);
                        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                            row.addElement(resultSet.getObject(i));
                        }
                        data.addElement(row);
                    }
                    resultSet.close();
                    statement.close();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    System.out.println(e1);
                }


            }
        });



/*          TableColumn column;
        for (int i = 0; i < table1.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            column = table1.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            column.setMaxWidth(250);
        }*/




}

private void addGrid(GridBagLayout gbl, GridBagConstraints gbc, Component c, int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, int weightx, int weighty) {
    gbc.gridx = gridx;
    gbc.gridy = gridy;
    gbc.gridwidth = gridwidth;
    gbc.gridheight = gridheight;
    gbc.weightx = weightx;
    gbc.weighty = weighty;
    gbl.setConstraints(c, gbc);
    add(c);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> firstly, when i tried to put 20020202 in this field, it occurred error about unexpected datatype. However, i don't know how to change number to 'Date'

Parse the String date into year, month and day values. Then you can create a `Calendar` 
object:

```
Calendar date = new Calendar(...);
```

Once you have the Calendar object you can create your SQLDate using:

```
Date sqlDate = new Date( date.getTimeInMillis() );
```

Note you should use the java.sql.Date class, not the java.util.Date class.

> the table doesn't show up.

The table doesn't show up because the columns are empty when the model is created. You need to create the model once you have the valid data.

So the code should be something like:

```
//DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
//JTable table1 = new JTable(model);
JTable table1 = new JTable(); // create empty table to add to scroll pane
```

Then after you get the data from the ResultSet you can create the model and assign it to the table:

```
resultSet.close();
statement.close();

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
table1.setModel( model );
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!
it was really helpful to fix my prob.